# How can I execute a method of a class in TypeScript by his name in string when I'm inside the class?

Tags: javascript, typescript, express, model-view-controller, logic

I'm working on a class to automatically create routes for Express and call a function in a controller. However, when I attempt to execute `this[methodName](req, res)`, I encounter the error message: 'Element implicitly has an 'any' type because an expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'AbstractActionController'. No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'AbstractActionController'.ts(7053).' I've searched extensively for an answer but haven't found one yet. I believe I need to specify types, but I'm unsure how to do so.

```
import AbstractActionControllerInterface from './interfaces/AbstractActionControllerInterface'
import { Application, Request, Response } from 'express'

class AbstractActionController implements AbstractActionControllerInterface {
    public alias: string
    private app: Application

    constructor(alias: string, app: Application) {
        this.alias = alias === 'index' ? '' : alias
        this.app = app

        this.registerActionRoutes()
    }

    /**
     * registerActionRoutes
     *
     * Called to log the routes with Action indicator in a controller.
     */

    private registerActionRoutes() {
        const classMethods = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(
            Object.getPrototypeOf(this),
        )

        for (const methodName of classMethods) {
            if (methodName !== 'constructor' && methodName.includes('Action')) {
                let route = methodName.split('Action')[0]

                route = route === 'index' ? '' : route

                this.app.all(
                    `${this.alias}/${route}`,
                    (req: Request, rep: Response) => {
                        if (typeof this[methodName] === 'function') {
                            this[methodName](req, rep)
                        }
                    },
                )

                console.log(
                    `[Lua]\x1b[33m Route ${this.alias}/${route} attached. \x1b[0m`,
                )
            }
        }
    }
}

export default AbstractActionController
```

I tried type with [key: string]: any but **this** has no indexes  maybe is something that i dont know.

Comment: Where do these methods come from? It seems that your class should have some index signature ``[method: `${string}Action`]: (req: Request, res: Response) => void``. Or maybe you just need to cast `classMethods` to `(keyof this)[]`?

Comment: These methods are accessible for any class that extends AbstractActionController. If I define a method named loginAction, I intend to execute that method when accessing the URL 'alias/login'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a [type predicate](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates) to narrow the type of your action function (type predicates were previously known as user-defined type guards).

This is the simplest version that would narrow your function:

```js
function isActionFunction(fn: any): fn is (req: Request, res: Response) => void {
    return typeof fn === 'function';
}
```

---

Here is the updated version of your code showing the its use in context:

```js
import { Application, Request, Response } from 'express'

function isActionFunction(fn: any): fn is (req: Request, res: Response) => void {
    return typeof fn === 'function';
}

class AbstractActionController {
    public alias: string
    private app: Application

    constructor(alias: string, app: Application) {
        this.alias = alias === 'index' ? '' : alias
        this.app = app

        this.registerActionRoutes()
    }

    /**
     * registerActionRoutes
     *
     * Called to log the routes with Action indicator in a controller.
     */

    private registerActionRoutes() {
        const classMethods = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(
            Object.getPrototypeOf(this),
        ) as Array<keyof typeof this & string>;

        for (const methodName of classMethods) {
            if (methodName.endsWith('Action')) {
                let route = methodName.split('Action')[0]

                route = route === 'index' ? '' : route

                this.app.all(
                    `${this.alias}/${route}`,
                    (req: Request, rep: Response) => {
                        const fn = this[methodName];
                        if (isActionFunction(fn)) {
                            fn(req, rep)
                        }
                    },
                )

                console.log(
                    `[Lua]\x1b[33m Route ${this.alias}/${route} attached. \x1b[0m`,
                )
            }
        }
    }
}

export default AbstractActionController
```